# Excel VBA issue with Ranges "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm brand new to VBA and using excel 2013.  I've been racking my brain all day with this error!  The lines marked with asteriks are getting 
*****"Application-defined or object-defined error"*****
**My function is supposed to do 2 things...**
1)  give the current cell a value
2)  change the fill color of another cell

There are no issues with #1, but #2 keeps erroring out
This is the code that I'm currently using...
I'm calling it from within the cell in excel, giving it the formula:  =ScoreIt()

```
Function ScoreIt()

Dim TotalVal As Integer, LRVal As Integer, LYVal As Integer, LGVal As Integer
TotalVal = 0
LRVal = 0
LYVal = 1
LGVal = 2

Dim CurrentRow As String, BedCell As String, Beds As Integer
CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
BedCell = Range("K" & CurrentRow).Address(False, False)
Beds = Range(BedCell).Value

If (Beds < 2) Or (Beds > 5) Then
    TotalVal = TotalVal + LRVal
    ** Range(BedCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 38 **
ElseIf (Beds = 2) Or (Beds = 5) Then
    TotalVal = TotalVal + LYVal
    ** Range(BedCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 36 **
ElseIf (Beds = 3) Or (Beds = 4) Then
    TotalVal = TotalVal + LGVal
    ** Range(BedCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 35 **
End If

ScoreIt = TotalVal

End Function
```

Thank you

Comment: Why not just make the `BedCell` a `Range` object and just call `set BedCell = Range("K" & CurrentRow)` then just use `BedCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38`

Comment: I've tried this already, it did not work either, BedCell returns the value in the cell rather than the cell's address/location.  I then tried adding .Address(False, False) to the end of it, but this just ended with a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

Worksheet formulas, even UDF ones, cannot change the property of a range object or return a value/change a property in another range object. The function's return value is restricted to the cell from which it was called.

I would suggest re-designing your code and split into a function for the return value, and a private sub for the colour change.

Here is an excerpt from the Microsoft Support site:

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot
> change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a
> function cannot do any of the following:
>
> -Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
>
> -Change another cell's value.
>
> -Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
>
> -Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
>
> -Add names to a workbook.
>
> -Set properties or execute most methods.
>
> The purpose of user-defined functions is to allow the user to create a
> custom function that is not included in the functions that ship with
> Microsoft Excel. The functions included in Microsoft Excel also cannot
> change the environment. Functions can perform a calculation that
> returns either a value or text to the cell that they are entered in.
> Any environmental changes should be made through the use of a Visual
> Basic subroutine.

You can find the full article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787